# powershell script to copy files from windows to multiple linux systems

Tags: powershell

I am trying copy a file from Windows to multiple Linux machines using Powershell script. The list of machines are read from a txt file. Tried using pscp to copy but it does not work. What could be an issue here? Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

```
$list = Get-Content C:\list.txt

foreach($host in $list) {

  Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -ArgumentList ("-scp -pw mypasswd C:\patch.sh root@$host:/root/")   

}
```

Comment: "but it does not work": how do you know? With out basic information (like the error message) you're asking for guesses.

Comment: sorry, missed to add this to my post.. i could only see a terminal which opens and closes immediately when executing the script. Looks like it is trying start pscp on the command line interface. When i run pscp manually from command line, it does show the paramters to use with pscp.

Comment: `-NoNewWindow` parameter of `Start-Process` will avoid a new console window being created.

Comment: Thanks Richard.. However now I am getting this error --
Local to local copy not supported
Local to local copy not supported
Local to local copy not supported
Local to local copy not supported

Comment: Isn't $host is a PS reserved variable? Do you get any errors whilst running the script? I would also suggest running a full command, for one host, as a test from the command line - this way you can see the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @obfuscate's note, that `$host` is a reserved, read-only varible, you might have issues with `root@$host:/root/` because of the colon.  The colon is a namespace identifier for variables. If you need to follow a variable with a literal colon, you should use curly braces.

Try:

```
$list = Get-Content C:\list.txt

foreach($remotehost in $list) {

  Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe' `
      -ArgumentList ("-scp -pw mypasswd C:\patch.sh root@${remotehost}:/root/")   

}
```